# router navigate not working in output event angular4

Tags: angular

I have a table component which emits an event with an id.

```
`@Output() onClick: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter<any>();`

`onRowClick(id: any) {
  this.onClick.emit(id);
  }`


`<a href="#" (click)="onRowClick(1)">
 </a>`
```

And on parent component

```
`<app-datatable (onClick)="onClick($event)"><app-datatable>`

`onClick(id: any) {
  this.router.navigate(['/employee-details']);
 }`
```

This doesn't navigate to employee detail page. but if i put a setTimeout it will work.

```
`onClick(id: any) {
    setTimeout(() => {
        this.router.navigate(['/employee-details'])}, 100
    );
  }`
```

Why is that so? Any work around for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try changing the `<a href="#" (click)="onRowClick(1)"></a>` to `<a [routerLink]="[link]"></a>` , and passing the link value to the child component as an `@Input()` property.

```
@Input() link
```

and inside parent:

```
<app-datatable [link]="'/employee-details'"><app-datatable>
```

i think when you put `href="#"` on the anchor tag, it will get in the way of angular's router.
alternatively you might be able to stop it by passing the event to your method, and calling `preventDefault()` on it, but the first way is the more standard way

Comment: Hi, your answer is also correct, but i don't want my data table to have more @Input's.

Comment: i'm specifically talking about the `<a>` tag and the way you're using it. generally `<a>` is used for links and not like a button. so if you want to do some actions (other than routing), it's more conventional to use buttons or div or span or... but if you want to navigate to some route in angular, it's recommended to use the built-in directive `routerLink`. unless in some special cases that you need to do some other things before navigating. but i think in your case, it would be more understandable to use `routerLink` instead of `href="#" (click)="onRowClick(1)"`

Comment: yeah, the problem is with anchor tag, if i use any other tag instead it will work without event.preventDefault(); 
Now i use     <p (click)="onRowClick(1)" class="link"></p>,it works absolutely fine.

Answer (score 1):

I think its a conflict between your click on  who trigger a location change and you router.navigate who also change the location.

Could you try to prevent the default effect on the  click ?

```
<a href="#" (click)="onRowClick($event, 1)">
 </a>
...
onRowClick(event: Event, id: any) {
    event.preventDefault();
    this.onClick.emit(id);
}
```

Comment: It worked, i put event.preventDefault(); only in my code. i think we don't need stopPropogation here!!?

Comment: yeah your are right, stopPropagation add nothing in your case