# navigation issue in angular 4

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I am working on an angular 4 project. I want navigate to another page on clicking any component

following is the component from where i want to navigate to another page.
this is the dashboard1 page from where i have to navigate to details page.

```
import { ThemeModule } from '../../@theme/theme.module';

import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { LocalDataSource } from 'ng2-smart-table';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';

import { Ng2SmartTableModule } from 'ng2-smart-table';
export class Dashboard1Component {

  ..
  ..
  ..
  onEdit(event) {
    console.log(event);
    this.router.navigate(['/details']);
  }
}
```

in pages-routing.module.ts i have done as follows

```
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { PagesComponent } from './pages.component';
import { DashboardComponent } from './dashboard/dashboard.component';
import { Dashboard1Component } from './dashboard1/dashboard1.component';
import { DetailsComponent } from './details/details.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: PagesComponent,
    children: [
      { path: 'dashboard', component: DashboardComponent, },
      { path: 'dashboard1', component: Dashboard1Component,},
      { path: 'details', component: DetailsComponent,},
      { path: '', redirectTo: 'dashboard', pathMatch: 'full', }
    ],
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule],
})
export class PagesRoutingModule {
}
```

it is navigating to details page on clicking edit and it is redirecting to dashboard page.
any help.

Comment: And... where is the route with the path 'detailscomponent' defined?

Comment: In children of dashboard1

Comment: No. All you have there is a path 'details'. And it's a child of dashboard1, so it's full path is '/dashboard1/details', not '/detailscomponent'. I think you need to take a step back, and re-read the routing chapter of the documentation.

Comment: i have not taken it as a child of dashboard1 it is another page similar as dashboard and dashboard1. i have edited it in my question

Comment: can you give any help

Answer (score 0):

now it's redirecting to '/detailscomponent', i think we need a routes path:'/detailscomponent' in the router module, could you please check, Thanks.

{ path: 'detailscomponent', component: DetailsComponent, },

Comment: I have done that also then also it is not directing to details page while it is routing to Dashboard page

Comment: did you checked it directly, i mean not inside children routes? as i think in ur case the children routes might won't work, please try

Comment: Are you using anchor tag as the button with onEdit() method?

Comment: could you please put a event.preventDefault(); before  this.router.navigate(['/details']); and check.

Comment: how can i put that is it required some imports

Comment: for using event.preventDefault doesn't need ant imports, please try.

Comment: i have tried it it showing me event.preventDefault is not a function and it is not navigaitng to anywhere.

Comment: Are you using the smart table given below link with Edit Link??
https://akveo.github.io/ng2-smart-table/#/

Comment: If you inspect the Edit link it's an anchor tag, i had similar issue before which i got solved with stackoverflow's help, please check this link below:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47548206/router-navigate-not-working-in-output-event-angular4

Comment: I am not getting it what should it here??

Comment: i have changed the anchor tag to a button and issue was solved.

Comment: but where i can do that it just imported it is already available in angular.

Comment: i understand, could please use (userRowSelect)="onEdit" instead of (edit) if you are using in table component. I have read the documentation, please go through it:
https://akveo.github.io/ng2-smart-table/#/documentation

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164240/discussion-between-nithalqb-and-faisal-amdani).

Comment: sorry as i am in office the chat option is disabled here.
nithalajay@gmail.com add me to chat.

Comment: sry i dont know how to add in chat.

Comment: you didn't used gmail chat?

Comment: will chat on hangout

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a route like that :

```
const routes: Routes = [

  { path: 'detailscomponent', component: DetailsComponent },

];
```

You can't navigate to the component like that :

```
this.router.navigate(['detailscomponent']);
```

Comment: can you give any help

Answer (score 0):

The route path for the details component is `details` as shown in the routes array:

```
path: 'details',
component: DetailsComponent,
}],
```

however you are navigating to a `detailsComponent` which is not defined in the routes. Therefore

```
this.router.navigate(['/detailscomponent']);
```

should change to:

```
this.router.navigate(['/details']);
```

Comment: i have done it also but it is not working i have edited it in my question.

Comment: can you give any help

Comment: I've tested the code and it works. Something must be wrong with the Details component

Comment: Can you share the details component as well?

Comment: `import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
selector: 'ngx-dashboard1',
  styleUrls: ['./details.component.scss'],
  templateUrl: './details.component.html',
})
export class DetailsComponent {
}`

Comment: Also, try changing `{ path: '', redirectTo: 'dashboard', pathMatch: 'full', }`  to `{ path: '', component: 'dashboard' }` just to see if the issue isn't on the redirect

Comment: My bad, change it to `{ path: '', component: DashboardComponent}`